# Error while running "podman run"; error adding pod to CNI network "podman": unexpected end of JSON input

Tags: containers, podman

I'm new to podman, and I just trying to run containers on it. 
(podman version 3.4.0, installed by `brew`, intel Core MAC)

However, when I trying to run "podman run {image-name}", below errors were thrown.

```
$ podman run -ti -d --name web httpd                                                 125 
Error: error configuring network namespace for container b0e70d672cb66005833c0a300c8661b88eab49e942c240d69d17587e0b75c47b: error adding pod web_2_web_2 to CNI network "podman": unexpected end of JSON input

$  podman run centos:7                                        
Error: error preparing container a6d0bc1ad217cd8207935561dc8ff7bd33672da3fa513917f9965cb39520c449 for attach: error configuring network namespace for container a6d0bc1ad217cd8207935561dc8ff7bd33672da3fa513917f9965cb39520c449: error adding pod quirky_snyder_quirky_snyder to CNI network "podman": unexpected end of JSON input
```

By reading https://issueexplorer.com/issue/containers/podman/11452, I removed `~/.docker/`, but the solution doesn't work in my case.

Of course, the error message says there was "unexpected end of JSON input", but I don't know how to fix it. Could anyone guess why podman didn't work even running these base images, or how to debug it?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I just found there was a bug report for this. https://github.com/containers/podman/issues/11837

Answer (score 2):

on macos, current `machine` version 3.3.1 has this problem. I had this problem on server version 3.3.1 and I do not encounter it on server version 3.4.0. You can check server version with `podman version`.

Try removing current machine and installing a newer one

```
podman machine stop
podman machine rm
podman machine init --image-path next
podman machine start
```

Check server version again with `podman version`.
Try running your image again.

Comment: Unfortunately, I got a problem with podman version 3.4.0, and solved a problem by workaround which was mentioned in https://github.com/containers/podman/issues/11837#issuecomment-941443898